# How many variables can be in local scope

Tags: c++, variables, translation

My question is pretty simple: how many variables can be in local scope to be properly translated?

I have to create a small translator (for studying purposes) from C++ to Assembly. During the translation process, there is a dynamic table of identifiers (variable names, in simple case, I suppose). How many can there be?

I mean, my table is dynamic anyway as well, but I need to create an array of tokens where each has 2 numbers - a table ID and a record ID in the table. So I want to know, which type should these IDs be - `int`, `short`, `long`, etc?

Comment: Interesting. I'm confident that different implementations have different limits and I'm not sure if the standard says something about a minimum amount.

Comment: The number of variables in local scope is probably not as critical as the available stack size at runtime (to provide sufficient storage for these variables).

Comment: A dynamic array as "local" variable seems to be impossible as C++ did not provide run time sized arrays. Dynamic allocation via new or indirect via a std::vector or other container type is using heap and not "local" stack.

Comment: Klaus, you totally missunderstood my question)

Comment: 1. You should add my name with an "@" so that I get a notification! 2. if you see that other users have misunderstood the question, why not make it more clear? Wood be nice to do it! Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How many variables can be in local scope

The C++ standard does not specify an exact maximum number.

It does have following *recommendation* (quote from latest standard draft):

> [implimits]
>
> Because computers are finite, C++ implementations are inevitably limited in the size of the programs they can successfully process.
> Every implementation shall document those limitations where known.
> This documentation may cite fixed limits where they exist, say how to compute variable limits as a function of available resources, or say that fixed limits do not exist or are unknown.
>
> The limits may constrain quantities that include those described below or others.
> The bracketed number following each quantity is recommended as the minimum for that quantity.
> However, these quantities are only guidelines and do not determine compliance.
>
> - Identifiers with block scope declared in one block ([basic.scope.block]) [1'024].

Someone wrote a test for this, and commonly used compilers appear to support at least 8k: https://github.com/fritzone/cpp-stresstest